# Best Way To Align Footer Elements inside footer

Tags: html, css

Im looking for an easy fix to align footer elements on the same 'line', consider this image:

[image]

Although one could argue the elments are linedup it is messy in that im using negative margins, and tables and floats.

Is there a better / easy way to achieve this, WITHOUT having to create extra  elements inside footer

Comment: It's probably possible, but we don't know your HTML markup and styles. Please put them into your question, and create working fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a positive margin and divs? Play around with the margin to get it as centered as you want.

```html
<footer style="background-color: lime; border:1px solid red; float:left; width:100%;">
  <div style="float:left;">
    Foo
    <br/>Bar
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:50%; float:left; text-align:left;">
    Swiggity swooty
    <br/>Bring
    <br/>Me
    <br/>That
    <br/>Booty
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;">
    Blah Blah Blajh
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Actually I would recommend using fixed widths combined with a set of responsive rules, but I don't know your requirements and situation well enough.